# PNG SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Trying to use a png file in my code:

```
import testImg from './test.png';
```

and getting the following error:

```
 SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

I understand that it's a problem with webpack, currently have the following in webpack related to images

```
 {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
    }
  },
```

So I'm not really sure why I'm getting that error, any ideas?